# Cannot get httpd to listen on port 80

Tags: homebrew, apache, services

I installed httpd using `brew`.

I edited `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` and changed:

```
Listen 8080
```

to:

```
Listen 80
```

Restarted the service:

```
brew services restart httpd
```

But Apache's still listening on port 8080:

```
Benjamins-Mac-mini:~ benjamin$ sudo lsof -iTCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN
Benjamins-Mac-mini:~ benjamin$ sudo lsof -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   24646 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   24647 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   24648 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   24649 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   24650 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   24651 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   34288 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   34289 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
httpd   34290 benjamin    4u  IPv6 0xcc42d5b2e5fcae09      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

**How can I force httpd to listen to port 80?**

I tried restarting the service using `sudo` as port `80` is a privileged port, with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had started another instance of `httpd` by mistake earlier. I typed:

```
httpd --help
```

And while `httpd` doesn't recognize this command (what I was looking for was `httpd -h`), **it did start a daemon**, that was listening according to the old config file.

I'm very surprised that `brew services start` *thought* it was starting the server properly (`brew services list` did display it as *started*), even though it probably wasn't running because of the conflicting instance.

This is really confusing as `start`/`stop` did toggle between "started" and "stopped", even though it probably wasn't doing anything under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a directive like this with 8080:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerName xyz.com
 etc…
 </VirtualHost>
```

You need to change that to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Make sure that you have correctly configured your directives for each subdomain you may have, including the default one (if it's been configured manually to listen to :8080 right after the name).

Comment: This didn't help I'm afraid, abd I checked for every single instance of `8080` in httpd's config dir, none left.

Comment: Then your system might be using 80. If should be launchd,

I suggest you look at this if you haven't done it yet:

https://superuser.com/questions/597398/no-idea-what-is-listening-on-port-80-in-os-x

Comment: The problem was not port `80` being in use, but another `httpd` process already running, see my answer. The *real* issue is `brew services` acting as if there wasn't a problem in this case!

Comment: Good, you managed.

Answer (score -3):

Go to file

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

Edit port in the file

```
Listen 80
```

then restart apache server

Comment: This is exactly what the question started with. They changed the file and restarted the process. Perhaps this would make a good answer on a question that didn’t do these steps?